# DataTable adding row alert error "Requested unknown parameter"

Tags: datatable, row, addition, message

Here is the error prompt when I try to add a new row in my DataTable.

> DataTables warning: table id=table-workshops - Requested unknown
> parameter 'name' for row 39, column 0. For more information about this
> error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example" id="table-workshops">
    <thead>
        <tr>                    
            <th>Workshop</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var workshops = JSON.parse(workshops_get());
var table = $('#table-workshops');

table.DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data: workshops,
    pageLength: 5,
    columns: [
        {data: 'name',},
        {data: "number",},
        {data: "category",},
    ],
    order: [[0, 'asc']]
});

$(document).on('click', '.workshop-add', function(){
    table.DataTable().row.add(['test', 'test', 'test']).draw();
});
```

Here is my table with loaded data (fine)

[image: myTable]

Here is my table with a new row but empty

[image]

I look at the multiple answers on the web but didn't find the solution for me.
I followed the doc of the official DataTable website.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Did anyone know where is the issue ?
Thank you.

Comment: What does `workshops_get()` return? Add an example to your question.

Comment: I assume (guess) it returns an array of objects - something like `[ { "name": "test", "number": "test", "category": "test" }, { ... }, ... ]`. But you are attempting to add an array `row.add(['test', 'test', 'test'])`. Look at the documentation for [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()): "_if your table uses objects, pass in an object with the same properties here!_". In other words, use an object, not an array. So, my guess would be `row.add( { "name": "test", "number": "test", "category": "test" } )`. But that is just a guess, not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, workshops_get() return an array as you mentionned.
You suggestion worked like a charm, thank you !

Comment: You can add that as a proper answer, if you want (but don't put the solution in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution given by @andrewJames worked, here is the correct code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.workshop-add', function(){
    table.DataTable().row.add( {"name":'test', "number":'test', "category":'test'} ).draw();
});
```

And here is the result :

[image]